# HTMLCollection and NodeList

Tags: javascript

Hello I have a problem where I am trying to grab all images so I can loop through them and add the event handlers below:

```
  addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
  addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
  addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
  addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
```

I am a little puzzled because I have tried getelementbyid to get the section area where all the images dynamically populate through AJAX.  Now in terms of querySelectorAl
l() doesn't seem to grab anything.  I am assuming I am just using this wrong.  Maybe it does not respond to tags.  But I tried with getElementsByTagName and it seems to grab everything and put it into an HTMLCollection.  Yet the HTML Collection's length is 0.  Is there a best practice way using Javascript (not jquery) to get these event handlers attached to each IMG?  I am at a lost here how to grab and then manipulate them.  .length does not seem to work and i'm not used to HTMLCollection which it seems is what I am getting.

```
var imagesContainer = document.getElementById("images");

var allImages = document.querySelectorAll('#images img');
console.log(allImages);
console.log(allImages.length);

var allImages2 = imagesContainer.getElementsByTagName("img");
console.log(allImages2);
console.log(allImages2.length);
```

Comment: Are you sure the images are already in the DOM when you try to find them?

Comment: is there a way to check?  From my understanding they are because HTMLCollection picks them up and shows the two images (although there can be more) with the two images.

Comment: I apolgoize, you are correct bfavaretto.  I put the code in my callback function after everything is definitely popuated and it does seem to work now.  I guess I will have to make sure to attach the event listener's in that function as well.  I did not realize it could get the image names and not get the length becuase of the way DOM seems to work.

Comment: That's why jQuery is useful for having a callback when the DOM has finished loading. You should write your update as an answer and accept it so others know how you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined that bfavaretto is correct.  To check if the dom was loading I moved the add event handlers to a place that would do it after the ajax call was complete for loading the images (checking readyState and readyStatus in an if statement).  I had not thought of this before because I personally had misunderstood how the DOM loaded it's HTMLCollection and array lengths and thought it was loading once everything was loaded.  Although it was grabbing all the images correctly the DOM was not loaded to grab and fully build the length from my understanding.